# How to implement unicode aware selection sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, unicode

I study selection sort algorithm. Consider this implementation:

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Selection.java.html

I have a text file which has unicode words like that.

```
$ more words.txt
şeftali içel ırak üzüm uzun çorba çimen ufuk
```

When I run the program it doesn't sorts unicode characters correctly.

```
$ java-algs4 Selection < words.txt
içel
ufuk
uzun
çimen
çorba
üzüm
ırak
şeftali
```

My first attempt was to use a collator.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class StringSorter
{
    public static void sortStrings(Collator c, String[] words)
    {
        String tmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; ++j)
            {
                if (c.compare(words[i], words[j]) < 0)
                {
                    tmp = words[i];
                    words[i] = words[j];
                    words[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printStrings(String[] words)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Collator tr_TRCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));

        String[] words = {"şeftali", "içel", "ırak", "üzüm", "uzun", "çorba", "çimen", "ufuk"};
        sortStrings(tr_TRCollator, words);
        printStrings(words);
    }

}
```

This program sorts words correctly as expected.

```
$ java-algs4 StringSorter
çimen
çorba
ırak
içel
şeftali
ufuk
uzun
üzüm
```

My question is how should we implement unicode aware selection sort algorithm in Java?

Also [Selection.class](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Selection.java.html) sort method takes a Comparator object as a second parameter. Is it possible to write our own implementation of Comparator interface so that it should be able to sort unicode elements correctly.

```
 public static void sort(Object[] a, Comparator c)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: These are being sorted by Unicode, what you appear to want to so sort by the latin letter character it most closely resembles.

Comment: You can use the normalizer for the characters, but you would need to add some code to handle when two characters normalize the same but are different. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Comment: A Collator **is** a Comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Collator` class implements the `Comparator` interface, so you can just pass `tr_TRCollator` to `Selection.sort` as the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you passing  tr_TRCollator to Selection.sort works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could Normalize the Strings and do a unicode comparison if they other wise match.

```
String[] words = "şeftali içel ırak üzüm uzun çorba çimen ufuk".split(" ");
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing((String w) -> 
                                        Normalizer.normalize(w, Normalizer.Form.NFD))
                             .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
Stream.of(words).forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
çimen
çorba
içel
şeftali
ufuk
uzun
üzüm
ırak
```

This is close but it doesn't consider `ı` to be like `i`

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that your 2nd example uses locale settings. Sort order for strings is locale dependent and has nothing to do with the unicode codepoints of the characters. Even countries that use the same language, say Austria, Germany and Switzerland have subtle differences in string sorting order.

Comment: Is there a Locale which defines a sort order for characters from multiple regions?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I don't see how this should work. As I said, even if the regions use the same character sets, sort order might be different.

Comment: ... and different people might have a different idea as to whether two characters look similar enough to be normalised to the same letter. There is 4 strategies built in to Java but none match what the OP wants exactly.